# Macro from Personal not working in other workbooks I want to copy one sheet to another workbook not personal

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA. I wrote a macro, I have data in workbook1 (only one Sheet1), I have workbook2 (only one Sheet2 which contains a formatted table). Workbook1 is created by the application, it contains rows of data, each time the workbook name is slightly different. What do I want to do?
in each new workbook1, run a macro, i.e. a personal macro, which will copy the table, i.e. sheet2 from workbook2, and then copy the value of the cells from workbook1(sheet1) to the appropriate cells of the workbook2(sheet2) table.
I created lines of code and it was fine, but something went wrong:

```
Public Sub CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook()
   Dim sourceBook As Workbook
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\..........\test.xlsm")
   sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
   sourceBook.Close
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  
'
' Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Copy
' Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
' ..........
'

  
' Worksheets("Sheet2").PrintOut
  
End Sub
```

now it looks like it copies Sheet2 as a new sheet to the PERSONAL file.
when I changed to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`
then the Sheet2 Table was copied as a new Sheet to Workbook2

I want it to create a copy of Sheet2 from Workbook2 to Workbook1 as a new Sheet2. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` ... before you open `sourceBook`.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where your code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Import Sheet From Closed Workbook Using `PERSONAL.xlsb`

```vb
Sub ImportSheetFromClosedWorkbook()
   
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    If dwb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No workbook open!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\..........\test.xlsm")
    
    swb.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Sheet imported in workbook """ & dwb.Name & """.", vbInformation
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Ben thanks a lot, You really helped me a lot. I couldn't find this answer on the web. I'm trying to write a macro for my company and it was quite a problem.